# Error no boot device found or disk failed ubuntu 14.0

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

i migrate from window 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04. I installed Ubuntu create swap area ,boot area and root .and follow all instruction.

install g partition and set flag boot area to grub_bios run boot repair.

But still error persist.

see this http://paste.ubuntu.com/12040152/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your system is installed in BIOS mode on gpt partitioned drive. You have to have a tiny unfomatted 1 or 2MB partition with the bios_grub flag. That is not a /boot partition, but just space for grub2's core.img as there is no space on gpt right after MBR as there is in MBR(msdos) partitioned drives. Generally better to not have a /boot partition with most desktops. Delete /boot partition & create the bios_grub unformatted space for grub. Then Boot-Repair can correctly install grub to MBR. Since system is UEFI was there a reason for BIOS, not UEFI install?

Comment: my system is both have uefi and legacy boot option. I turn off secure boot and fast boot . l initially left 1 mb unformatted disk space.

Comment: But in BIOS boot mode, you need a bios_grub partition. That is a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios-grub flag. Without that partition grub will not correctly install. Your bios_grub flag is on a large formatted partition and seems to be confusing a /boot with a bios_grub partition.

Comment: I create  partition of 86 GB  install ubuntu on that and initially left 6mb space unallocated. i come to live Ubuntu  and 6mb space allocated to unformatted set flag type bios_grub using gpartition.
run boot repair and restart computer nothing happen same error 
occuring every time.how can i see whaether boot repair working correctly or not .
here is my new pastebin
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12048759/

Comment: It shows grub correctly installed to MBR & core.img in bios_grub partition. If you hold shift key from BIOS  do you get grub menu? You do know that Windows will only boot from gpt partitioned drive with UEFI? It looks like you have a BIOS install of Windows that will not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can see whether Boot Repair is working by attempting to boot after it's done. You've done that, and it's *not* working in your case. That's not to say it's necessarily Boot Repair's fault, though; a lot of things that Boot Repair cannot control, or even detect, can affect the boot process. I have some specific comments on your setup (some of which aren't boot-related per se), based on your *second* Boot Repair output:

- You have four NTFS partitions, but it appears you have no Windows installation. (One of these four NTFS partitions is a Windows recovery partition, though.) It's possible that the Boot Repair output is missing the evidence of a bootable Windows partition; but if not, either you've accidentally trashed your Windows installation or you deliberately deleted it. If the former, you should stop fiddling with Ubuntu and fix Windows before proceeding. If the latter, you should *not* be using NTFS on a Linux-only installation, for numerous reasons. Unless you've got data on those NTFS partitions that you want to preserve, you're best off deleting them and continuing with Linux-native filesystems.
- You're using BIOS/CSM/legacy mode on a computer that almost certainly uses an EFI/UEFI. Using the CSM creates all sorts of problems, as detailed on [this page of mine.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) In particular given your symptoms, you sometimes need to play games with partition table details when booting an EFI-based computer from a GPT disk in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. There's a significant chance that this is why your computer won't boot with your current installation. You're probably better off disabling the CSM and doing an EFI-mode install.
- It's possible that a leftover NVRAM entry from your Windows installation is blocking a BIOS-mode boot of your Ubuntu. You might be able to fix this by adjusting the boot priority settings in your firmware setup tool, but precise details of how to do this vary from one system to another, so I can't provide detailed instructions. Performing a fresh EFI-mode install of Ubuntu should override any leftover Windows NVRAM entries, which of course is another reason to do a fresh EFI-mode install of Ubuntu.
- If you *do* have a Windows installation, it must necessarily be in EFI/UEFI mode. Mixing an EFI-mode Windows installation with a BIOS-mode Ubuntu installation is a recipe for frustration. Thus, if Boot Repair has missed a Windows installation, my general recommendation to install Ubuntu in EFI mode becomes a very strong recommendation.
- Your disk is not big enough to need GPT. Given the presence of occasional quirks of BIOS-mode booting from GPT disks, you're probably better off switching from GPT to MBR if you want to stick with BIOS-mode booting. This can be done non-destructively with `gdisk`, as described [here;](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html#gpt2mbr) however, there are caveats, and you'll need to re-install GRUB. Unless you need to preserve those NTFS partitions, you're probably better off wiping the disk clean and starting with a fresh MBR.

Overall, your best bet is to start clean:

1. If your NTFS partitions hold files you want to preserve, back them up to an external medium.
2. Wipe the hard disk with `sudo sgdisk -Z /dev/sda`. ***This command is destructive!***
3. Disable the CSM in your firmware.
4. Boot the Ubuntu installer. It should boot in EFI/UEFI mode, as indicated by the presence of a directory called `/sys/firmware/efi`. (You can look for this directory by booting to "try before installing" mode and using a Terminal or file manager. If the directory is present, you can run the installer from the same boot.)
5. Install Ubuntu. Use default partitioning or the "Something Else" option, as you see fit. If the latter, I recommend the following partitions:

   - A ~550MiB [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition)
   - A partition a little bigger than your RAM for swap space
   - A 20-30MiB Linux root (`/`) partition
   - The rest of your disk as a `/home` partition
   - Note that there's seldom a need in Linux for multiple data partitions

After you install Ubuntu, the system should boot normally. There are multiple questions and answers here about installing Ubuntu in EFI mode, as well as information and tutorials elsewhere. For more information, check out:

- [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- Adam Williamson's [blog entry on how EFI/UEFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)
- The Ubuntu wiki's [page on installing under EFI/UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)
- My [page on EFI/UEFI-mode Linux installations](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

I strongly recommend you read these pages before posting back with more problems; you'll be in a much better position to understand what's going on, and therefore to post a question that will produce a useful response, after you read the preceding pages. Ideally, you'll learn enough that you'll be able to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Thanks Rod Smith i am really appreciating your help and learn new things too.Thanks alot.